# add "check if fetchmail is running" to this script

Tags: bash, process, scripting, fetchmail

```
while ! postqueue -p | grep -q empty; do
  sleep 1
done
killall wvdial
```

this script checks if my mail queue is empty, then disconnects my modem. now i would like to add also a checking to fetchmail if is running. i am not sure how to develop it but i know that it can be something like the down example.

```
while ! postqueue -p | grep -q empty && "fetchmail process is not running"; do
```

some help please?

Comment: Nerdhacker's postqueue week on SF.

Comment: And the next question is already in the queue ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Checking mail queue and fetchmail process"
while ! postqueue -p | grep -q empty && ps -C fetchmail > /dev/null; do
  echo "There is still mail in queue or fetchmail is still working"
  sleep 1
done
echo "Terminating the connection"
killall wvdial
```

Comment: Yes, and i have more questions still in queue ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
while [ "`find /var/spool/postfix/{deferred,active,maildrop}/ -type f | wc -l`" -gt 0 ] ||
      [ "`ps -C fetchmail -o pid= | wc -l`" -gt 0 ]; do
    sleep 5
done
killall wvdial
```

or even with fewer spawned processes:

```
while [ -n $("find /var/spool/postfix/{deferred,active,maildrop}/ -type f") ] ||
      [ -n $("ps -C fetchmail -o pid=") ]; do
    sleep 5
done
killall wvdial
```

Comment: ``[ "`somecommand | wc -l`" -gt 0 ]`` is an awfully indirect way of checking for empty output. `[ -n "$(somecommand)" ]` is the direct way. You can do better though, see [nerdhacker's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24428#24428). Also, you should be testing postfix and fetchmail at the same time rather than never test postfix once you've started testing for fetchmail (there's still a race condition, but the window is a lot smaller). Oh, and **always put double quotes around substitutions**. What do you think would happen if the output contained whitespace (like, several lines)?

Comment: @mailq I've corrected what was objectively wrong. I'll leave the correct-but-suboptimal stuff up to you.